# async function declaration expects ';' in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have an async function declaration that works on Chrome and Firefox, but gives the following error in internet explorer.

SCRIPT1004:  Expected ';'

File: javascriptFile.js, Line: 5, Column 7

This is the simplified version with these two function at the top of the file, and it still fails on internet explorer.

```
function sleep (ms) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) { setTimeout(resolve, ms) })
}

async function begging (help) {
  await sleep(1000)
  console.log('please')
}
```

I can not seem to find anything about not being able to declare async functions in internet explorer.  I would really appreciate any help at all, I'm not sure where to look next in order to figure this out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Internet Explorer does not support [`async`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions) functions, and never natively will. The main drawback of using new JavaScript features is lack of support.

[image]

Comment: Is there a polyfill for this?

Comment: @CarlosMartins you can transpile your code for older browsers using tools like babel. But there's no pop-in polyfill for this as it's new syntax