# Cannot find module that's been specified in babel.config.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

I'm new to using Babel but have installed it according to the Installation guide here https://babeljs.io/setup#installation

It says at the end that you need to install plugins in order for it to work:

> Now, out of the box Babel doesn't do anything ... You will need to add plugins for Babel to do anything.

I want to use this plugin: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator to fix some Internet Explorer 11 issues as described here: [async function declaration expects ';' in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681318/async-function-declaration-expects-in-internet-explorer/45681357)

I've created a file in the root of my project called `babel.config.json` and added the following to it.

```
{
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator"]
}
```

My `package.json` contains this:

```
"scripts": {
     "build": "babel webroot/js -d webroot/js/babel"
},
"devDependencies": {
     "babel-cli": "^6.0.0"
},
```

When I execute `npm run build` from my project root it gives the following error messages.

```
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator' from '/Users/andy/my-project'
```

Prior to creating `babel.config.json` I *was able* to run `npm run build` without getting any errors. As per the quote this doesn't really do anything other than output the same JavaScript as I had before transpiling it. But I knew that the process worked - in my case the input files are in `webroot/js` and it outputs the equivalent transpiled files to `webroot/js/babel`.

I don't understand how to fix this error. Is this some issue with my config file or is additional setup needed?

I've read the documentation on Babel Config Files at https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files and found this incredibly convoluted. My goal is to have a configuration file per project, which is why I opted for `babel.config.json`

npm version is 6.13.4, node version is 12.16.1.

Comment: There's a bug in a babel package... see related issues:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8680
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17262

Those are relevant to react and angular but hopefully help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`babel-cli` is outdated, you should install `@babel/cli` instead. It also has a peer dependency on `@babel/core` which you need to install as well. `@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator` plugin needs to be installed separately.

Summarizing:

- Uninstall outdated `babel-cli`:

```sh
npm uninstall --save-dev babel-cli
```

- Install the required packages:

```sh
npm install --save-dev @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator
```

---

Regarding your problem with IE 11. `@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator` won't fix your issue. IE 11 doesn't support [`yield`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_yield).

If you want to use the latest ECMAScript features and still support a wide range of browsers you should instead use `@babel/preset-env`. You can check out the docs on the official website: [`@babel/preset-env`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env).

For `async` to work in IE 11 you will also need to setup polyfills. `@babel/preset-env` won't use them with default settings. Look under [`useBuiltIns`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins) option for instructions.

---

Additionally, there's a problem with your build script, specifically with this line: `babel webroot/js -d webroot/js/babel`.

With such a command babel will process whole `webroot/js` directory (including subdirectories) and place transpiled files to `webroot/js/babel`. This means that after you run this command again it will process not only your original source files but also transpiled source files because `webroot/js/babel` is a subdirectory of `webroot/js`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Regarding the last paragraph about `webroot/js` - it's a CakePHP application and that's the default location for .js files. Ideally the transpiled files need to end up there, using the same name as the source. So ideally I'd want `webroot/js/app.js` to be transpiled by Babel but then end up in `webroot/js/app.js`. I realise these are the same name/location so something needs to change. Is there a way to do this in the build script or is it more of a deployment process type of issue? The files will be developed inside `webroot/js` as that's a standard in CakePHP

Comment: @Andy CakePHP only needs to know about js files it will serve i.e. transpiled files and not your source files.
I recommend keeping your sources and transpiled files separate.
You can put your js source files in e.g. `src/js` and then use `babel src/js -d webroot/js` command to transpile those files.
If you rather want to keep your source files in `webroot/js` and transpiled files in `webroot/js/babel` you can use `babel webroot/js -d webroot/js/babel --ignore babel` command to tell babel to ignore files inside a directory called `babel`.

Comment: I've changed my `babel.config.json` to contain `"plugins": ["@babel/preset-env"]` as you mentioned this is the correct module to fix the issues in IE 11. When I run `npm run build` it errors with: `Error: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-preset-env'`. I have installed it as per your instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install `@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator`. More here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator#install

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator
```